# Difference b/w command field and template field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

What is the difference between command field and template field in grid view and how can I use them in grid view?

I am new in c# so please provide full help so I can feel easy to work with both.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`CommandField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.aspx)  enables to display command buttons to perform selecting, editing, inserting, or deleting operations in a data-bound control.

A [`TemplateField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx) enables to display custom content in a data-bound control. You could for example nest another `GridView` inside it or a custom `WebUserControl` which consists of several other controls.

So in short:

- a `CommandField` autogenerates a button or link for special actions like edit/delete
- a `TemplateField` is extremely customizable, you can put anything there

Answer (score 2):

Template fields are fields where you add controls inside gridview columns.
And command fields are the attribute through which you came to know which control has generated event inside girdview.

Answer (score 1):

In [template field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you can place any asp.net control, you can customize it.

From MSDN:

`Represents a field that displays custom content in a data-bound control.`

[Command Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.aspx):

From MSDN:

`Represents a special field that displays command buttons to perform selecting, editing, inserting, or deleting operations in a data-bound control.`

Answer (score 0):

Templete Field :- If U Want To do Some More Action in GridView Like Editing , Display Images etc Then U Hav To Use Templete Filed.